# Apply JSON to TextFields or Selects based on a value in the JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui

I have a bunch of JSON groups pulled from an API. Each group contains 1 or more `questions` objects. I need to append each question to a textField with its corresponding `response` in either a MUI TextField or Select, which needs to be decided based on the `QuestionType` value.

Below is how I am trying to get data to display to a TextField.  The TextFields are being populated with `[object Object]` as they are now.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState("");

const fetchQuestions = async () => {
   setQuestions(
      await fetch(`/fiscalyears/FY2023/intakes/${params.id}/details/questions`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
   );
};

...

{questions["question_groups"]?.map((row) => (
   <TextField
      fullWidth
      multiline
      className="text-field"
      value={row?.questions || ""}
      variant="outlined"
      margin="normal"
      label={row["GroupName"]}
   />
))}
```

Here is an example of my JSON.  In reality, there could be 20 groups within `question_groups`

```
{
   "question_groups": [
      {
         "GroupName": "DDD",
         "questions": [
            {
               "Question": "1. Do you need a drink?",
               "QuestionType": "Select",
               "Response": null,
               "Choices": [
                  "Yes",
                  "No"
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "GroupName": "FED",
         "questions": [
            {
               "Question": "2. What do you want to drink?",
               "QuestionType": "Text",
               "Response": null,
               "Choices": [
               ]
            },
            {
              "Question": "3. Do you want something to eat?",
               "QuestionType": "Text",
               "Response": "I would like steak",
               "Choices": [
               ] 
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: from where are you getting `question_groups` API or constant?

Comment: ``question_groups`` is from the API.  I have updated the question to show the API call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two components for each `QuestionType`.

```
const SelectQuestion = ({ question }) => {
 return (
        <Box>
          <TextField value={question?.Question || ""} />
          <Select label="Question" >
            <MenuItem value={question?.Choices || ""}>{question?.Choices || ""}</MenuItem>
          </Select>
          <Divider />
        </Box>
      );
};

const TextQuestion = ({ question }) => {
      return (
        <Box>
          <TextField value={question?.Question || ""}/>
          <TextField />
          <Divider />
        </Box>
      );
};
```

Map the array of `question_groups`, then map the array of `questions` in each group and return one of the component types depending on the value of `QuestionType`

```
const questionComps = questions["question_groups"]?.map((group, i) => {
        return group["questions"]?.map((question, i) => {
            return question["QuestionType"] === "Text" ? (
                <Box>
                    <TextQuestion key={`${i}${question.Question}`} question={question} />
                    <Divider />
                </Box>
            ) : (
                <Box>
                    <SelectQuestion key={`${i}${question.Question}`} question={question} />
                    <Divider />
                </Box>
            );
        });
    });
```

Now render the question components

```
return (
        <div>{questionComps}</div>
    )
```